# Fill a matrix using R *apply functions

Tags: r, apply, nested-loops, lapply

I have a matrix with that needs to be filled up with values. The first row of the matrix will have the same value and the subsequent row values would be generated using a function based on the first row value

I can do this using nested for loop like this. The outer loop goes over the column, sets the first row in that column to value. Then the inner loop fills up the rest of the rows in that column using the fn. The function itself takes the previous row value as its input.

```
fn <- function(value){ value + 1 }
myMatrix <- matrix(NA,5,3)
value <- 100

for(col in 1:ncol(myMatrix)){
    myMatrix[1,col]<-value #First row value for all the columns should be the same
    for(row in 2:nrow(myMatrix)){
        #Rest of the row values generated using fn
        myMatrix[row,col] <- fn(myMatrix[row-1,col])
    }
}

myMatrix
```

I don't want to use a for loop and would like to specifically achieve this using one of R's vectorized *apply functions. I tried this but its not working.

```
fn <- function(value){ value + 1 }
myMatrix2 <- matrix(NA,5,3)
value <- 100

sapply(1:ncol(myMatrix2), function(col){
        myMatrix2[1,col]<-value
        sapply(2:nrow(myMatrix2),function(row){
            fn(myMatrix2[row-1,col])
            })
    })
```

**EDIT :**

I was able to achieve it using sapply and the <<- assignment operator for filling up the matrix. But, is there a more cleaner/efficient way to do it using the *apply family ?

```
fn <- function(value){ value + 1 }
myMatrix2 <- matrix(NA,5,3)
value <- 100

myMatrix2[1,]<-value #first row of the matrix to have the same value
sapply(1:ncol(myMatrix2), function(col){
    sapply(2:nrow(myMatrix2),function(row){
        myMatrix2[row,col] <<- fn(myMatrix2[row-1,col])
        })
    })

myMatrix2
```

Comment: What are the loops trying to do? Could you please summarise what is being done?

Comment: `value <- 100; 
myMatrix <- matrix(value:(value+nrow(myMatrix)-1),5,3)`

Comment: I think you should either include your actual `fn` that you want to apply or make this `fn` bit more complicated since there are lot of hacks which can be used to get the output that you have shown which would work for the example shown but not for your real data.

Comment: `m <- 5; value <- 100; myMatrix <- matrix(value:(value+m-1), m,3)`